# How to adjust the width between the bars in android

Tags: android, bar-chart

[image]

Can any one tell me how to adjust the width between the bars?please let me know that java code.Above image will make you clear.

Thanks in advance!..

Comment: I can see that you're using an `ImageView` to show a graph of some sort. You'll have to draw a new one in GIMP, Photoshop or even MS Paint and include it as a resource in the drawable folders. Then set the `android:src` attribute in your layout xml to point at the new resource. Seriously though, you have to show us how this is implemented. Correcting a couple of lines of your code is more feasible than reverse engineering your app from a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AChartEngine, use the `setBarSpacing(value)` method in the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`:

```
renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
```